# Read after writes on Firestore server libraries

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firestore docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention say:

> Only the server client libraries support transactions with read operations after write operations.

However, when reading after writing using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore 4.7.2 I am getting:

> Error: Firestore transactions require all reads to be executed before
> all writes.
> at Transaction.get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:76:19)

Is reading after writing on server libraries actually supported?

Comment: Are you using the Node *client* package, or the node *admin* package?

Comment: I realized I had both firebase-admin and @google-cloud/firestore dependencies on my package.json. That doesn't look right but both of them should be server SDKs right?

Comment: Both of them are the latest versions: @google-cloud/firestore 4.7.2 and firebase-admin 9.4.1 (which brings @google-cloud/firestore 4.5.0 )  Maybe I am actually using this last one and that version doesn't contain this feature?

Comment: Couldn't find anything related to this feature on https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes

Comment: @google-cloud/firestore is SPECIFICALLY the Node **CLIENT** sdk.  The difference between allowing read-after-write isn't Node; it's whether you're using Client or Admin.  It would likely *help* if we saw *any* of your actual code - are you making these transaction calls from a *client* app instance or from an *admin* app instance? Do you *need* both Client & Admin (I'm running multiple Cloud Functions using Firebase-admin with no reference to @google-cloud/firestore).

Comment: I'll add that I wrote a "wrapper" for my Firestore calls - so I could substitute someday, if needed, by just changing the wrapper - and I use the exact same wrapper for client and/or admin - just changing whether I instantiate the admin or client version.  That's how my Cloud Functions deploy works (all the functions in the *same* tree/repository).

Comment: As per [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#isolation_within_a_transaction), server client libraries support transactions with read operations after write operations. Please read the [Transactions Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions). Could you please share your code in order to determine the issue?

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274448/11753380)