# How to implement Firebase transactions with read operations after write operations

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to implement **read operations after write operations** in nodejs for cloud and background functions?

As stated in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#isolation_within_a_transaction), only server client libraries support transactions with read operations after write operations. But I can't implement one to not trigger error:

```
Error: Firestore transactions require all reads to be executed before all writes.
    at Transaction.get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:76:19)
    at /workspace/lib/firestore/tests-write.js:46:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Transaction.runTransaction (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:323:26)
    at async /workspace/lib/firestore/tests-write.js:43:5
```

I'm using `"firebase-admin": "^9.6.0"` that uses `@google-cloud/firestore "4.5.0"` and
`"firebase-functions": "^3.13.2"`

Background function (trigger):

```
const onFirestoreTestsWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('tests/{testId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
      const testDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('tests').doc().get();
      t.set(testDoc.ref, {});
      t.get(testDoc.ref);
    });
  });
```

Cloud function (http):

```
const tests_get = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const test = await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
      const testDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('tests').doc().get();
      t.set(testDoc.ref, {});
      return t.get(testDoc.ref);
    });
    res.send({id: test.id});
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: e['message'] });
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you retrieving the document to return it?  YOU JUST SET IT - use the value you set as the return value.

Comment: @LeadDreamer it's just to showcase writes before reads. The main reason of question more complex

Comment: If you think this is a bug or the docs are incorrect, then file a bug report on GitHub for the library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#isolation_within_a_transaction) stated wrong and server libraries doesn't support reads after writes. Documentation will be fixed soon.

From the point of code, there's no way to overcome such situation.